# useStep hook function not working with onClick arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, onclick, arrow-functions

My goal here is that when people click on the submit button, it will raise an alert if the user did not enter anything into the text box. But if they did enter something, it will advance to the next page using `next`. I can do one or the other, but when I try to do both, only `checkInput()` runs.

I also have noticed that when I try to use `next` with an arrow function, it doesn't work anymore (which I suspect is part of the reason). Can someone explain why I can't use `next` in that way? Also, any advice as to how I can have both functions run with `onClick`?

```
const checkInput = (input, navigation) => {
  if (!input.trim()) {
    alert(
      'Please leave a response. If your listening environment has not changed, "N/A" and similar responses are acceptable.'
    );
  }
};

const Feedback = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const { next } = navigation;
  // const clickHandler = txt = {

  // }

  return (
    <div className="container grid">
      <ReactMarkdown
        children={`#### **Post-Evaluation Survey**\n ${text.post_eval} \n\n**NOTE:** Your answer will not affect your 
                compensation.`}
      />
      <textarea
        rows="4"
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="My neighbor started moving their lawn."
      ></textarea>
      <div className="section col-2 align-right">
        <a
          href="#"
          className="button"
          onClick={() => {
            checkInput(input);
            next;
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Feedback;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about including next inside check input instead?

```
const checkInput = (input, navigation) => {
  if (!input.trim()) {
    alert(
      'Please leave a response. If your listening environment has not changed, "N/A" and similar responses are acceptable.'
    );
  } else {
    next()
  }
};
```